# Beautifulsoup get span content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have parsed html page: using beautifulsoup

```
user_page = urllib2.urlopen(user_url)
souping_page = bs(user_page)
badges = souping_page.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'badges'})
```

after this my `badges` object looks like this:

```
<span><span title="9 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">9</span></span><span title="38 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">38</span></span><span title="56 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">56</span></span></span>
```

Now I want to extract example `9 gold badges`, `38 silver badges` from this, I tried to use `badges.span.span` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get the parent `span` from `badges`, find all top-level spans inside by using `find_all()` with `recursive=False`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = """<div class="badges">
<span>
    <span title="9 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">9</span></span>
    <span title="38 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">38</span></span>
    <span title="56 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">56</span></span>
</span>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
badges = soup.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'badges'})
for span in badges.span.find_all('span', recursive=False):
    print span.attrs['title']
```

prints:

```
9 gold badges
38 silver badges
56 bronze badges
```

Hope that helps.